# I keep getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when i try to implement an upload function on my flask application

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, flask

Part of my development requires me to upload files into my application and store it somewhere. And during the development phase, I decided to create a dummy folder on my desktop - "uploads" to store all the uploads that went through my flask application. But when i was testing the function, i kept getting the following error message - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. Can anyone explain to me what is happening? and i am doing this project on a corporate laptop, could that be the reason?

I have tried multiple ways, but i have yet to get the admin rights to run the command prompt

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import DBConnector, os, get_function, pandas as pd, numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:\\Users\\chyesh\\Desktop\\uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'csv', 'xlsx'])

app.secret_key = "hello123"
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] ='filesystem'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'datafile' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect('/')
        file = request.files['datafile']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No files selected for uploading')
            return redirect('/')
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']), filename)
            flash('File(s) successfuly uploaded')
            return redirect('/')
```

Expected to save the uploaded files on my "uploads" folder on my Desktop but it did not execute as expected.

Comment: This is a port number issue. Change the port that you're working on to a high number such as 5000

Comment: I changed the port but still does not solve the problem. And I am working on a corporate laptop, could that be the reason?